# handling matrices with rows of unequal length in R

Tags: r, matrix, division

There are two matrices that I want to divide: `numer1` and `denom1`. The problem is that they are of unequal row lengths. The script is run every week, so the dimensions change weekly, too.

This week:

```
dim(numer1) = 998 rows, 99 columns 

dim(denom1) = 997 rows, 99 columns.
```

Last week:

```
dim(numer1) = 999 rows, 99 columns 

dim(denom1) = 998 rows, 99 columns.
```

Is there a way to compare these matrices and remove the last row in the larger matrix (in this example, `numer1`)?

Here's what I have tried:

```
fun1 <- as.data.frame(abs(numer1[-last(numer1),]/denom1))
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
rows <- 1:pmin(nrow(numer1), nrow(denom1))
frac1 <- numer1[rows,] / denom1[rows,]
```